# Object material does not support subscription error add webhook in serviceM8

Tags: webhooks

I tried to add webhook in servicem8 as the document at http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/platform-services/webhooks/

But i got this error {"success":false,"message":"Object material does not support subscription"} .

I tried both job and material object but still same error.
I am using trial account.

Anyone have experience with this , please help.

Here is detail POST via postman

POST /webhook_subscriptions HTTP/1.1

Host: api.servicem8.com

Authorization: {Hide information}

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 64b8e5ea-55c3-6fc9-1936-c19436bd72c9

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

object=jobmaterial&callback_url=http%253A%252F%252Frequestb.in%252Fzkqdd1zk&fields=status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try varying the object name and see if that solves the issue, instead of material, try Material.

Also ensure your callback_url is a valid and reachable URL, as the webhook subscription will fail if it's not reachable/valid.